# Problemas com contour() no python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Olá, estou tendo alguns problemas com a função contour() do pylab.
Na imagem final, os valores do eixo x e y estão variando de 0 a 600, que foi a quantidade de intervalos no meu arange(). Porém, eu queria que estivessem os valores de x e y (-3 a 3)

```
from numpy import exp,arange
from pylab import meshgrid,cm,imshow,contour,clabel,colorbar,axis,title,show
q=3
def z_func(x,y):
 return exp(-((x**2)+((y/q)**2))/2)

x = arange(-3.0,3.0, 0.01)
y = arange(-3.0,3.0, 0.01)
X,Y = meshgrid(x, y)
Z = z_func(X, Y) 
im = imshow(Z)
cset = contour(Z,linewidths=2)
clabel(cset,inline=True,fmt='%1.1f',fontsize=10)
colorbar(im)
title('$z = e^{-(x^2+(y/q)^2)/2}$')
show()
```

Eu tentei colocar contour(X, Y, Z), mas a situação só piorou... 
Provavelmente é algum pequeno detalhe, desculpa se a pergunta for muito boba, mas eu já tentei de tudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode definir o intervalo do seu vetor usando o argumento `extent` no `imshow` e `contour`

```
from numpy import exp,arange
from pylab import meshgrid,cm,imshow,contour,clabel,colorbar,axis,title,show
q=3
def z_func(x,y):
 return exp(-((x**2)+((y/q)**2))/2)

x = arange(-3.0,3.0, 0.01)
y = arange(-3.0,3.0, 0.01)
X,Y = meshgrid(x, y)
Z = z_func(X, Y) 
im = imshow(Z, extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])
cset = contour(Z,linewidths=2, extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])
clabel(cset,inline=True,fmt='%1.1f',fontsize=10)
colorbar(im)
title('$z = e^{-(x^2+(y/q)^2)/2}$')
show()
```

[image: imagem]